# DCOS simple load balancing tutorial Part 2 erroring

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, mesosphere

I have been working through the Mesosphere DCOS Tutorial and can't seem to get [Part II](https://docs.mesosphere.com/tutorials/deploy-load-balanced/) to work. To the best of my knowledge, I have followed their instructions exactly and Part I went just fine.

The problem seems to be in the router, so I posted my router code to Github at [tnbeatty/dcos-tutorial-2](https://github.com/tnbeatty/dcos-tutorial-2). I built this container image and pushed it to Docker Hub, as the tutorial suggests.

The container JSON object in nginx-router.json contains the following:

```
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "mesosphere/simple-docker-router",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
          {
              "containerPort": 8080,
              "hostPort": 80,
              "protocol": "tcp"
          }
      ]
    }
```

When I change the image to "mesosphere/simple-docker-router," my load-balanced app works and scales just fine. When I try to use my image ('tnbeatty/simple-docker-router'), the page does not load.

I am at a loss at this point because the app seems to deploy just fine on Mesosphere DCOS - no discernible errors or warnings to be found. Any thoughts or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I thknk what your nginx-router is missing:

```
"acceptedResourceRoles": ["slave_public"]
```

Which will make it so that your container will launch on the "public slaves" and therefore be available when you go to the "Public Load Balancer" address on your DCOS cluster.